# Which is the correct way to dynamically use variating static data

Tags: ruby, database, data-structures

Following basic principles what would be the preferred way to structure a program and its data that can variate but is used to accomplish the same "standard" task? It should easily be extendable to include more providers. 

For example:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'open-uri'

class AccountFetcher 

    @@providers = {}
    @@providers['provider_a'] = [
        'http://url_for_login_form.com/', 'name_of_form',
         # the number of fields can vary between different providers
        [ ['name_of_field', 'value_for_it'], ['another_field', 'another_value'] ],
        ['name for username field', 'name for password field']
    ]
    @@providers['provider_b'] = [
        'http://another_url.com/', 'another_form_name',
        [
            # array of more fields that are specific to this form 
        ],
        ['name for username field', 'name for password field'] 
    ] 


    # looks more nice using AccountFetcher.accounts opposed to @@accounts 
    def self.accounts 
       @@providers
    end 


    # example of a method that uses information that can vary
    def self.fetch_form(agent, account_type)

        # the first element in the array will always be the url
        page = agent.get(AccountFetcher.accounts[account_type][0])

        # the second element in the array will always be the name of the form
        form = page.form(AccountFetcher.accounts[account_type][1])
    end 


    def self.initialize_form(agent, account_type)

        form = AccountFetcher.fetch_form(agent, account_type)

        # will cycle through all fields that require 'pre-filling'
        AccountFetcher.accounts[account_type][2].each do |f|

            # f[0] will always be the name of the field and f[1] will
            # always be the value for the field; however, the amount of
            # fields may vary
            form.field_with(:name => f[0]).value = f[1]
        end 

        form 
    end
```

So the general idea is use a class variable that consists of a hash and has arrays containing the appropriate data elements. I would need to do this for every class that has similar functions. 

Another idea I had would be to replace the class variables and instead turn each provider into a class database that can be accessed by the other classes. So `provider_a` would become:

```
class ProviderA

    # all the possible information needed
    # methods will have similar names across all the different providers
end
```

And the appropriate provider can be chosen by

```
class Providers

    @@p_providers = {}
    @@p_providers['provider a'] = ProviderA.new
    @@p_providers['provider b'] = ProviderB.new
    @@p_providers['provider c'] = ProviderC.new
    @@p_providers['provider d'] = ProviderD.new

    def self.return_provider(name)
        @@p_providers[name]
    end
end
```

Is the former or latter solution more appropriate? Or is there a more 'ruby-ish' solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store this configuration values in an external YAML file. Your configuration file could looke like this:

```
# config/providers.yaml
provider_a:
  url: 'http://url_for_login_form.com/'
  name: 'name_of_form'
  fields:
    - name: 'name_of_field'
      value: 'value_for_it'
    - name: 'another_field'
      value: 'another_value'
provider_b:
  url: 'http://...'
  ...
```

You could load that file with `YAML.file_file` that returns nested hash in this example.

```
require 'yaml'
def AccountFetcher
  def self.accounts
    @accounts ||= YAML.parse_file("config/providers.yaml")
  end
  #...
end
```

You may want to consider using a Gem like [`has_configuration`](https://github.com/spickermann/has_configuration) that makes handling the data structure a bit easier.